# How to display JSON data in a select box using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my JSON data:

```
{
  "ACT": "Australian Capital Territory",
  "NSW": "New South Wales",
  "NT": "Northern Territory",
  "QLD": "Queensland",
  "SA": "South Australia",
  "TAS": "Tasmania",
  "VIC": "Victoria"
}
```

How to display this JSON data in a selectlist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way (takes fewer function calls):

```
var myJson = {
  "ACT": "Australian Capital Territory",
  "NSW": "New South Wales",
  "NT": "Northern Territory",
  "QLD": "Queensland",
  "SA": "South Australia",
  "TAS": "Tasmania",
  "VIC": "Victoria"
};

$.each(myJson, function(key, val) {
  $('#mySelect').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + val + '</option>');
});
```

Comment: Works for this dataset but in the general case you need HTML-escaping to replace `<`, `&` and `"` characters in the data, else you've got HTML-injection leading to XSS security problems. It's usually best to avoid HTML string-slinging when you can.

Comment: @bobince - I see what you mean. Does calling `.val()` and `.text()` a sufficient avoidance of that issue?

Comment: Yep. And `.attr()` for other cases.

Answer (score 5):

Use $.each and iterate over all your elements. This should work:

```
$.each(jsonData, function(key, value)
{
   $('<option></option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo('#yourSelectList');
});
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the data, many .append() operations can be expensive.  It's much faster to create a placeholder array, and .push() each option onto it, then .append(myArray.join('')) only once.

Comment: This is wrong. What the heck is `this.code` and `this.name`? It doesn't work at all. Have no idea why this is getting up-voted.

Comment: MightyE: that would only make any sense if we were talking about HTML strings. (And even then, jQuery's `append` function still has to append each DOM Node one-by-one, so you don't save anything by doing it like that.)

Comment: @patrick You're completely right. Got a little to fast. Updated my answer.